# find maximum distance in set of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

We are give a tree `T`, and a set of nodes initially empty `P={}`.
we have 3 kind of operations:

```
1.add a node to `P`
2.delete a node from `P`
3.Query for maximum distance in set `P`
```

we have total of `q` operations and the time limit says that we should do the whole operations in O(q* log(n)).
So we need to do each operation in `O(log(n))`

So far i did this :

```
keep track of max distance in each insert/delete operation. 
for insert it's just to check the distance of added node from two previous max nodes
for the query it's just return max_distance
```

but for `delete` operation i cannot do better than `O(n)` (finding max distance between set of nodes on tree without any further information)
is there any `O(log(n))` solution for this?

Comment: "Query for maximum distance in set `P`" Maximum distance from what?

Comment: When adding a node, can you build a skewed binary tree?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur from each other in set `P`

Comment: Have you tried to think of this problem using a LCA approach ?

Comment: Do inserted nodes always become leaves? Are deleted nodes always leaves? If not, how is deletion defined? Do all children of the deleted node become children of the deleted node's parent? Is this about *any* tree, or binary tree? If binary, then how is deletion defined of an internal node?